# Custom table name for each device in PostgreSql

Tags: typescript, postgresql, dynamic, controller, loopback4

To dynamically set the table name based on the device ID in LoopBack 4.

In loopback 4 , need to create separate table for each user , i.e table name with their device id .
eg: motor_log_device_id

Need to pass table name dynamically from device.controller.ts. Need help with that.

My model.ts file

```
// Model definition without dynamic table name
@model()
export class MotorStatus extends Entity {
  @property({
    description: 'Motor log ID',
    type: 'number',
    id: true,
    generated: true,
    index: true,
  })
  id: number;

  @property({
    description: 'Motor packet sync at',
    type: 'date',
    required: true,
    index: true,
  })
  created_at: string;
}
```

```
const SETTING = {
  settings: {
    postgresql: {
      schema: 'public',
      table: 'dbtablename'
    }
  }
}

@model(SETTING)
export class MotorStatus extends Entity {
  @property({
    description: 'Motor log ID',
    type: 'number',
    id: true,
    generated: true,
    index: true,
  })
  id: number;

  @property({
    description: 'Motor packet sync at',
    type: 'date',
    required: true,
    index: true,
  })
  created_at: string;
}
```

Is there any way to pass table name dynamically to SETTING and set to model decorator.